# GTM - Virtual page views & Goals

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have a web site that already has GA page tracking and Goals set up to track conversion based on URLs, and these are working fine via GTM & GA.

We want to introduce a new product and track it via a separate goal/funnel.
Problem is the pages stay the same, so there isn't any change in the URL to differentiate when a customer has selected this product.

Our flow is as follows:

```
/Price
/Up-sell
/Summary
/Payment
/PaymentComplete
```

The customer selects the product on the Price page.

In order to get the Goals to track for this new product I've created a series of virtual page views that are triggered when the product is clicked and persist on subsequent pages.
So the URLs within GA now look like:

```
/Virtual/Price
/Virtual/Up-sell
/Virtual/Summary
/Virtual/Payment
/Virtual/PaymentComplete
```

I can see the page views within GA fine.
When I create a new goal I base it off the /Virtual/ urls.

However, because GA is firing on each page by default I effectively get two URLs in GA the original URL, e.g. /Price AND /Virtual/Price this then causes issues tracking between pages in the funnel & goal.

What am I doing wrong here?
How does everyone else manage this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can add exceptions to the GA trigger in GTM, add the URLs that you don’t want. Or, don’t fire the trigger that sends the virtual page.

Comment: Thanks for recommending this.
I've added exceptions to the default loading of GA for all pages, however, as these were added as trigger group exceptions they all fire at trigger group level and don't effectively block the default GA page view, as the default runs when gtm.js equals gtm.js.

Looks like I may need to find a different way to block the default page view from loading.